# how can i get the comments of video from googlePlus in iOS6?

Tags: video, ios6, comments, google-plus

In my application im sharing video on googlePlus programatically using GooglePlus API, my requirement is i need to get the comments of that video from googlePlus programatically.

I gone through the Google API site but in that link i need too give the activity ID.Can any one suggest me hoe can i get the activityId programatically?

Comment: GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForActivitiesListWithUserId:@"me" collection:@"public"];
        [plusService executeQuery:query
                completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                    GTLPlusActivityFeed *actFeed,
                                    NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
                    } else {}  using actFeed we can get the comments

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks details, so I can only respond with a generic answer based on my experience.
I have an iOS app that parses information from various websites.

Essentially, I first check to see if there is connectivity to the website, if there is connectivity I download the HTML source and place it in a NSString object. I store that string in the user settings (which is NOT the proper way of doing it, but it works for me) so that I can parse that HTML the next time they use the app with no connectivity.

I parse a NSString object containing the HTML source and display the information I want to the user. Parsing html source on the device is not a good idea. The next time the website updates it could possibly break your app, as it happened to me. I had to quickly submit an update to my app, but it took Apple 7 days to approve, which meant users started removing my app from their devices.

The solution is to setup a server (direction I'm going). You can buy your own server (don't recommend it) or use BaaS (Backend as a Service) providers (i.e. Google app engine, parse.com, and many others) and parse from the server, then have your app request data from the server. The next time the website changes you just update the parsing on the server.

Comment: As Backend as a Service Provider you can use apiomat.com. The advantage there is that you don't have to model your data on the client, instead you get an sdk with your individual datamodels generated. apiomat has partners that make modules like that kind that you need very fast. just ask the support there.

Comment: I'll take a look at this service